# How to inject a parent component into a shared directive without specifying component type?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

How can I define my directive for use it in all component :

**my directive.ts :**

```
import { Parent } from '../../_common/Parent';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private parentCmp: Parent) {
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-aero',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-aero'
    }).on('ifChecked', function(event) {
      if (jQuery('input').attr('type') === 'radio') {
        parentCmp.selectType(jQuery('input[name="filters.type"]:checked').val());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**my Parent.ts**

```
export abstract class Parent {
 }
```

**My component.ts (using icheck)**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Parent } from '../../_common/Parent';

    declare var jQuery: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-folders',
      templateUrl: './folders.component.html',
       providers: [{ provide: Parent, useExisting: AdminEditComponent }]
    })
    export class FoldersComponent implements OnInit, Parent {

         name = 'FoldersComponent ';

      constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
      ) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

      selectType(value: string) {
         console.log(value);
      }
    }
```

**my component.html :**

```
<input type="radio" icheck checked> => here how can I define an event for calling method **selectType** ?
```

Here, we can see that I use the component in param FoldersComponent, so when I want to use this directive (icheck) in other component (like AppComponent), I got error .. 
How can I do for make it global for all component ..
NB : In folderComponent I define method **selectType** called when I select a button radio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Angular modules support components/directives/pipes encapsulation you need to use a pattern called `shared modules`. Create a module and put your directive into the declarations of the shared module and then import that module into every module with components that use this directive. Here is the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-module) on shared module.

**EDIT:**

As I understand, you want to be able to use `icheck` directive with any component and not hardcode type of parent component here `private parentCmp: FoldersComponent`. This can be done in the following way:

1) Define a token that will be used for parent injection. It can be a simple class like this:

```
export abstract class Parent { }
```

2) Define a provider on the component that will be used alongside `icheck`:

```
@Component({
   providers: [{ provide: Parent, useExisting: AnyComponent }]
})
export class AnyComponent implements Parent {
   name = 'AnyComponent';
}
```

3) Use this token inside `icheck`:

```
export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, @Optional() private parentCmp: Parent) {
```

Here is [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jakD3OLQtdXajGxO5kYH?p=preview)

Comment: Ok thx, but I don't understand .. Its worked fine in the component FolderComponent  because I want to use the method selectType) .. but when I removed it in param it's work fine in all component  .; but I can't use after the method selectType

Comment: vendor.bundle.js:1443 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No `provider for FoldersComponent!
Error: No provider for FoldersComponent!
    at injectionError (vendor.bundle.js:1590)
    at noProviderError (vendor.bundle.js:1628)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (vendor.bundle.js:3129)`  .. because I am positionned in an other component ..

Comment: But without using directive, Can I called method in a ts file since my component html ? like `<input type="radio" (click)="method" ...>`

Comment: Hi! Seems you forgot about using `forwardRef` for `useExisting: AnyComponent`

Comment: @yurzui, hey, I thought it was not required in this case, was it? :)

Comment: I tried it and I got error : `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Parent!
Error: No provider for Parent!`   I will update my first post for showing you what I do

Comment: something is wrong with your setup then, check [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jakD3OLQtdXajGxO5kYH?p=preview)